# Switch case, getText of the case android

Tags: android, switch-statement, textview

I have a simple switch case:

```
switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.one:

        break;
        case R.id.two:

        break;
        }
```

What I would like to do is write something smart and self sufficient to obtain the text value of the mentioned textviews. For example r.id.one holds text of 1, while r.id.two holds text of 2. 
Whenever I press 1 I want to get it's text value. 
I know it can be done by the following way:

```
TextView one = (TextView)findviewbyid(r.id.one);
one.getText();
```

But with the increase of textviews it will be hard to maintain, as I want to use the obtained value later on.

Thanks advance to all the downvotes, really helpful.

Solution:

```
switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.one:
        String number = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
        break;
        case R.id.two:
        String number = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
        break;
        }
```

Now number receives the value from the textview. Thanks all.

Comment: "with the increase of textviews it will be hard to maintain" .. "I want to use the obtained value later" ? you need to keep values but not the views (o.O)    !

Comment: In my case I don't manage any data. All I was needed, to obtain value, from textview without declaring the textview in every single case, to make a method I can use in every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a switch, you can try to get the text if the view is any TextView. For instance:

```
if (view instanceof TextView) {
    ((TextView) view).getText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's exactly what I was looking for.
Writing this inside the case:String number = (String) ((TextView)view).getText(); have provided me with the number from my textview.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library.

Use something like :

```
@OnClick({R.id.textviewID1, R.id.textviewID1)
protected void onTextViewClick(TextView textView) {
   textView.getText();
}
```

This allows you to use the same callback function for each textview using just a simple annotation.

And makes the code more readable as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something simple without the use of third-party libraries.